# Insert a magit-section without refreshing the buffer

Tags: magit

I'm experimenting with [magit-section](https://melpa.org/#/magit-section) as the UI library for an Emacs package. Without going into too much detail, this package interfaces with a websocket and displays the data it receives as an expandable line in the buffer, preferably as a `magit-section` item. Nested inside it are more `magit-section` items with other data categories.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out, how to insert a section dynamically (on a websocket message). The following works well enough on buffer setup:

```lisp
(magit-insert-section (root-section) ;; top-lvl section containing all buffer data
    (magit-insert-section (list-section) ;; first visible section with a heading
        (magit-insert-heading "Websocket messages:")
        (magit-insert-section (item-section nil t) ;; nested data is hidden
            (magit-insert-heading "List item:")
            (magit-insert-section-body
                ;; more data and sections
              ))))
```

But adding an `item-section` to the `list-section` dynamically is very difficult.

Is it possible? If it is, how?

I'd really prefer `magit-section` because of it's ergonomics (setting a specific keymap for every section).

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info